# python, print intermediate values while loop

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am sorry if this is very basic, I am new to programming. 
When I run my code, only the last value is printed.
How can I modify my code, so that the entire list in range N is displayed, using a while loop?

```
x0 = 100 
p = 5 
N = 4 
i = 0

x = []
while i <=N:
    i += 1
    xn = ((1 + (p/100))**i)*x0
x.append(xn)
print(x)
```

Comment: BTW, you would normally use a `for` loop for this in Python, but I guess this is an exercise in using `while` loops.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't indent the x.append. So the code is not inside the loop and only the last value is appended to x. Correct would be:

```
while i <=N:
    i += 1
    xn = ((1 + (p/100))**i)*x0
    x.append(xn)
print(x)
```

Comment: @bence: Since you are new here: If my answer helped you, pleae accept it by clicking the check-mark under the vote buttons. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Your indenting is slightly off, but beyond that you can simply add the print statement to the while loop

```
x0 = 100 
p = 5 
N = 4 
i = 0

x = []
while i <=N:
    i += 1
    xn = ((1 + (p/100))**i)*x0
    x.append(xn)
    print(xn)

print(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to put the x.append(xn) inside the while loop. Otherwise only the last xn will be appended to x.

```
x0 = 100 
p = 5 
N = 4 
i = 0

x = []
while i <=N:
   i += 1
   xn = ((1 + (p/100))**i)*x0
   x.append(xn)
print(x)
```

Comment: print(x) does not have to be in the loop. In fact it is wrong if the author wants to display only the complete list...

Comment: You are correct, thanks. I have edited it immediately after posting, and it should be correct.